# 140it with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I try to shorten some text using the http://140it.com/ service over AJAX, but I always get an empty response.

Example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://140it.com/api/shrink",
  data: {text: 'hello'},
  success: function(d) { alert(d) },
  dataType: 'html',
  type: 'GET'
});
```

If I execute the url manually (like browsign the web) I get the response.
Fix? Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the JSONP format of the [api](http://140it.com/api/) which uses the callback parameter

```
http://140it.com/api/shrink?char_max=5&text=today&callback=do_something
```

Use jQuery's [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot perform cross-domain AJAX requests.

I.e. If your site is hosted on domain A.com, you cannot do a $.ajax request to B.com.

One of the solutions is to use a server-side proxy script on your own domain. For instance, you could have PHP do the request to 140it and have jQuery call your script instead of 140it directly. This is described in this article: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html

The other solution is to use JSONP web services which allow you to specify a callback function and can be called by appending a SCRIPT element to your page. However, not all API providers offer JSONP.

- Christian

Comment: Here's some more info on that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting.